# Whats the best way to add relevant and short information next to the button to help users go to the next page?

Tags: buttons, conversion, call-to-action

On the website I'm working, users ask very frequently when do they get to do the upload to finish the order. Its a printing business, so users want to upload asap, but we dont want to storage all those files, so we allow only the upload to be done after payment is confirmed.

To answer that question, I'm thinking of adding additional info next to the buttons - along the funnel - that goes to the next page saying something like "Upload after payment". Pls dont pay attention to the copy as the website is not in English, but something will be added to unsure them when the Upload will be done.

I've seen it in a few websites, some add the text in below the button, but I don't remember where I've seen it and I'm not sure if it should be inside the button or below the button.

What do you guys think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned about funnel, but probably wrong interaction could narrow it with paying barrier.
[image]

It's very useful to design user flow, which has low barriers and smooth interaction. Payment can break the flow, if it:

- requires large manual data input,
- requires redirection to payment system site.

On the contrary, payment supports flow if it happens parallel to file uploading, as it saves the time. Also having uploaded a file user become tied to your site. So paying looks more logical, as the part of work is done.

You could try A/B testing to make better decision, but even now you could watch exit rate for the current design.

**UPDATED**
Still, having limited storage space, you could incentive (with price, speed, etc.) users not to upload files, but provide links to files at their cloud storages (like Dropbox, etc.) and provide links to popular cloud storages.

Answer (score 1):

**First scenario**

Maybe you can also make the user experience a little bit clearer for them by adding some sort of short instruction? I'm not sure what service do you provide, but here's an example fo such instruction:

- Select your plan/number of copies
- Fill in order details
- Enter payment information
- Upload your mock-ups/files/data

This way you can show the users what and when do they need to expect when working with your website.

**Second scenario**

How often do you see users uploading their files and then payment not being confirmed? Maybe you should just make what's best for users - allow them upload the files before the payment page?

Comment: +1 for the second scenario - that's the decision for better UX.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a multi-stage form process if you're not already and show the steps at the top of the page, updating as the user progress along the process. Something like this:

[image: Sign up process]

From this it is immediately clear to the user what steps they will be taking along the process, in what order and where they are now.

I do agree with others that only uploading after payment could cause users to lose interest. You could consider allowing the user to upload but only keeping their uploaded files for a certain time period if they don't pay.

This means if they wan't to go away and make an informed decision (within a specified period of time) they can do so without having to go through the process of uploading files again.